# building internet based p2p text,audio , video chatting application

Tags: asp.net, sockets, tcp, udp, p2p

I would like to implement internet based P2P text,audio, and video chatting application using c# asp.net socket programming. i'll use tcp sockets for text chatting and udp sockets for video and audio chat application.

i would like to go with wpf, please suggest me whether wpf supports my task, or any other asp.net frame work which is more suitable for my requirement

thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You should consider about using SIP protocol. There is no open source .net library for SIP. But many popular SIP lib has .net wrapper, pjsip e.g. (https://sites.google.com/site/sipekvoip/)
See also open WPF SIP softphone based on MS UCCAPI.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/officesip/